# Count by Group with condition

Tags: sql, partition

I have a dataset like below:

```
  Col_A    Col_B    Col_C    Col_D     Metric_1
10/1/19        A     NULL        Z            5
10/1/19        A       AB        Z           10
10/1/19        A                 Z           12
10/1/19        B       AC        J            7
10/1/19        B       AB        J           12
10/1/19        B                 J           13
```

How do I get the count of Col_C where it is not NULL or Blank ''? My dataset contains user level data and I want to pretty much get the count where NULL or Blank is not included.

```
  Col_A    Col_B    Col_C    Col_D     Metric_1     COUNT_COL_C
10/1/19        A     NULL        Z            5               1 
10/1/19        A       AB        Z           10               1
10/1/19        A                 Z           12               1 
10/1/19        B       AC        J            7               2
10/1/19        B       AB        J           12               2 
10/1/19        B                 J           13               2
```

My attempt looks like this, but it is saying the result is 3 for both instead of 1 and 2:

```
Dataset_Result AS (SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN COL_C IS NOT NULL AND COL_C != '' THEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COL_A,COL_B, COL_D) END 
COUNT_COL_C
FROM ORIGINAL_DATASET)

SELECT * FROM Dataset_Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just doing a normal count with a group by and no CTE or window functions should work for what you say you need.

```
    SELECT Col_A, Col_B, Col_C,Col_D, Metric_1, COUNT(*) 
    FROM ORIGINAL_DATASET
    where COL_C IS NOT NULL AND COL_C != ''
    group by Col_A, Col_B, Col_C,Col_D, Metric_1
UNION 
SELECT Col_A, Col_B, Col_C,Col_D, Metric_1, COUNT(*) 
    FROM ORIGINAL_DATASET
    where COL_C IS NULL AND COL_C = ''
    group by Col_A, Col_B, Col_C,Col_D, Metric_1
```

EDIT1:
Better approach

```
SELECT  
COUNT(CASE WHEN COL_C IS NOT NULL AND COL_C != '' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS COUNT_COL_C
FROM ORIGINAL_DATASET
```

Comment: If I do that then it would remove the nulls from the final dataset

Comment: @nak5120 I just made an edit to my answer it's not the most elegant way to do it but will get you the results you are looking for I think.

Comment: This actually works for some reason when you so not include the case when statement in the count and rather just do `COUNT(COL_C)  OVER (PARTITION BY....`

Answer (score 1):

You can move the conditional inside the window function:

```
;WITH Dataset_Result AS (
  SELECT *, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN COL_C IS NOT NULL AND COL_C != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY COL_A,COL_B, COL_D) 
COUNT_COL_C
FROM ORIGINAL_DATASET)

SELECT * FROM Dataset_Result;
```

See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cb8e1/2 for an example.